# WPF DataContext works differently in seemingly identical situations

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I have the following resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="b" Color="{Binding B}" />
    <my:C x:Key="c" Prop="{Binding Source={StaticResource b}}" />
    <my:C x:Key="d" Prop="{Binding A}" />
    <Ellipse x:Key="e" Fill="{Binding A}" />
    <Ellipse x:Key="f">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding B}" />
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</Window.Resources>
```

My window has a data context declared like this:

```
<Window ... DataContext="{my:Context}" ...>
```

Custom classes C and Context are defined like this:

```
public class Context : MarkupExtension
{
    public Brush A { get; } = Brushes.Blue;
    public Color B { get; } = Colors.Red;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}

public class C : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Prop", typeof(Brush), typeof(C));
    public Brush Prop { get { return (Brush)GetValue(PropProperty); } set { SetValue(PropProperty, value); } }
}
```

Now, the ways in which I use my data context and binding seem very similar to me, yet if I check my resources with the following code (inside a button click handler)

```
MessageBox.Show("f: " + ((FindResource("f") as Ellipse).Fill?.ToString() ?? "null"));
MessageBox.Show("e: " + ((FindResource("e") as Ellipse).Fill?.ToString() ?? "null"));
MessageBox.Show("d: " + ((FindResource("d") as C).Prop?.ToString() ?? "null"));
MessageBox.Show("c: " + ((FindResource("c") as C).Prop?.ToString() ?? "null"));
MessageBox.Show("b: " + (FindResource("b") as SolidColorBrush).Color.ToString());
```

I get this result:

```
f: #00FFFFFF
e: null
d: null
c: #FFFF0000
b: #FFFF0000
```

i.e. only the last two are seemingly correct. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Strange.

my:C has obviously no DataContext and can therefore not bind directly to anything.

Resources with DataContext do not inherit the resources owner's DataContext (Ellipses e and f)

SolidColorBrush "b" derive form System.Windows.Freezable which has a protected Field/Property called InheritanceContext which for "b" is set to the MainWindow. I think it has access to the Context.B through this reference and that's why "b" and "c" shows the right color.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this, and so decided to play around with it a little. I am nowhere near an expert on XAML, but I wanted to share my findings in case it helps out at all.

I added the following XAML to a `Grid` on the page:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource b}" />
<Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Fill="{Binding Source={StaticResource c}, Path=Prop}" />
<Ellipse Grid.Row="2" Fill="{Binding Source={StaticResource d}, Path=Prop}" />
<ContentControl Grid.Row="3" Content="{StaticResource e}" />
<ContentControl Grid.Row="4" Content="{StaticResource f}" />
```

Here is a screenshot of the results:

[image: Ellipse Screenshot]

The following binding error appeared in the Output window, which I think explains why `d` is not filled:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=A; DataItem=null; target element is 'C'
>   (HashCode=60275915); target property is 'Prop' (type 'Brush')

It looks like it may be having trouble resolving the binding for `d` because it can't locate its position in the element hierarchy, and so can't resolve the DataContext.

I also noticed that if I commented the XAML out, the behavior was exactly the same as was posted in the question. Both `e` and `d` were null. Based on this, it seems like the usage of the resources may impact whether or not the binding can be resolved at runtime.

It would be great to hear from someone with more insight into the internal workings of how bindings function in resources.